# handling nulls and zero values in django

Tags: django, null

If I have a model with a nullable field:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    parameter = models.FloatField(blank=True,null=True)
```

I then want to handle this in a view or template.

If something.parameter has a value, I want to return the value, and if it is null, I want to return 'N/A'.

If I use:

```
something = Something.objects.get(id=1)
output_string = 'parameter value: %s' % (something.parameter or 'N/A')
```

then this works, except in the case where something.parameter=0, which also returns 'N/A' rather than the desired '0'.

How can I correct this behaviour?

Is there a way of doing this directly in the template?

Answer (score 8):

Use the [`default_if_none`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none) template filter:

```
{{ value|default_if_none:"N/A" }}
```

Comment: thank you. What would be the correct way of doing this in the view as above? (there is a reason why I need to do this)

Answer (score 0):

You could filter your data by **isnull** (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#isnull)

```
something = Something.objects.filter(parameter__isnull=False)
```

Then you can check if your query returns any results and set your parameter accordingly:

```
if something:
    parameter=something[0].parameter
else:
    parameter="N/A"
```